# PHP : my cookies are not deleted after closing the browser

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have some difficulties with my php code. I need to modify the part of code of my colleague and I don't understand what's happen.

In the signin page, he checked for the login and password, and if it's ok, a $_SESSION start and the user can access to the application.

The problem is, if the user doesn't click on the deconnexion link and quits the page (even if he closes the browser or shuts down the pc), he's always connected. I checked and there is a cookie.

My first question is why this cookie exists because there are no setCookie() in the code.

This is the part about session in my php.ini :

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "N;/path"
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly = 
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
```

So I need to know how to delete the cookie when the user closes the browser. (I can't define a value for expiration because the application uses some processing which can take a lots of minutes before having the results).

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Angelique

Comment: I do not remember however maybe this string session.cookie_lifetime = 0 will tell how much time you are logged into the system, how much "life" has the session and 0 stand for "forever"

Comment: @Goikiu : Yes it is. But if I put a value, the problem is that the user could lose the result he wants because the page's load is too long (i use hadoop for big data). I don't know if i'm really cleau :s

Comment: Yes, you're clear, you will ask too run too much time (more than the ini settings).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just delete any cookie, because you can't guarantee there's actually such a file - the contract between browser and web server regarding cookies is that the data will be presented at eligible requests.

You need to set expiration date for [coockie](http://us.php.net/setcookie) you wish to delete to a time in the past. Then the browser should automatically remove it.

Comment: But I don't understand this : ; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime
session.cookie_lifetime = 0 => so why the cookie is always here even if I close the browser ?